# Using RecyclerView as the child of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

[I built a horizontal scrolling list as the child of ExpandableListView. The horizontal list is made up by RecyclerView and CardView. Please click this link to see the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSSzx.png)

Everything seems to be fine, but some of those horizontal scrolling lists would act weird. I was hoping to keep the position of the scrolling list the same no matter how many time I expand or collapse the same or different group. For example, if I expand the group "Comp 203" and after I scroll the horizontal list, we can see "assignment14" as the first in the horizontal list. I want to keep "assignment14" as the first no matter how many time I expand or collapse that group or different group.

However, when I expand other group such as "Comp 202", the horizontal list in the group "Comp 202" would look exactly the same as the one in the group "Comp 203".

```js
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            assignmentList =
                    (List<Assignment>) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
    
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                recyclerViewAssignment = (RecyclerView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
                //if (recyclerViewAssignment == null) {
                assignmentAdapter = new AssignmentAdapter(assignmentList);
                mLayoutManager =
                        new LinearLayoutManager(this.context,
                                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                recyclerViewAssignment.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                recyclerViewAssignment.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                recyclerViewAssignment.setAdapter(assignmentAdapter);
                //}
                assignmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

I only left the method getChildView() in the CustomExpandableListAdapter because I am suspicious that the problem is in there.

Comment: What happens when you collapse "Comp 203" and expand it again? Will it just go to the first position? That's the default behavior.

Comment: Right now, it won't but it will replicate the position of other group. Before this version, it did go to the first position because I create the RecyclerView without checking if convertView is null. I was wondering if we could keep the position no matter how many time we expand and collapse the same or different group.

Comment: You have to keep track (with a variable of an apt type, for example an int[]) by yourself and use it to reposition your list once you return to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of if block I used a HashMap to store the newly created child view, and I tried retrieve it at the third line of 'getChildView()'.

```java
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final List<Assignment> assignmentList =
                (List<Assignment>) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);

        String groupName = (String)getGroup(listPosition);
        convertView = assignmentRecyclerViewList.get(new Integer(listPosition));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            AssignmentAdapter assignmentAdapter;
            RecyclerView recyclerViewAssignment;
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

            recyclerViewAssignment = (RecyclerView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);

            assignmentAdapter = new AssignmentAdapter(assignmentList);
            mLayoutManager =
                    new LinearLayoutManager(this.context,
                            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

            recyclerViewAssignment.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerViewAssignment.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerViewAssignment.setAdapter(assignmentAdapter);

            assignmentRecyclerViewList.put(new Integer(listPosition), recyclerViewAssignment);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Then, I call the 'getChildView()' in the MainActivity inside of OnGroupExpand of ExpandableListView.

```java
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int i) {
                expandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildView(i, i, false,null,null );
            }
        });
```